# How to disable calls but still receive texts

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, calls

Is it possible through a setting or an app to receive only text messages and not phone calls?

Specifically I have an Samsung galaxy s3

Comment: Not tested: you could disable the Dialer, go to `Settings > Applications > Phone` (or possibly 'dialer') and disable. Not a great work around. You could route it to your Google Voice mail if you have that set up. You could use a blacklist app: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sriseshaa.android.myblocker or https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.incorporateapps.callblockerlite and see if you can block only calls... Let me know if anything suits or works and I'll expand a fuller answer.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about the Galaxy S3, but my S5 has the option to disable just the calls. Open the Dialer → Settings → Call → Call → Rejection → Auto rejection mode →All incoming calls.

Answer (score 0):

Use call forwarding. Forward to a number which is not in the network.